# connect to postgres using epgsql with sslmode=verify-full

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, erlang

Here is how I connect to a postgres instance using `epgsql` in erlang:

```
epgsql:connect("example.com", 
               "user", 
               "secret", 
               [{database, "whatever", 
                 {ssl, true}, 
                 {cacertfile, "cacert.crt"},
                 {certfile,   "user.crt"},
                 {keyfile,    "user.nopassword.key"},
                 {verify, verify_peer},
                 {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}
                ])
```

I can't set `sslmode=verify-full` here like in `psycorg2` in python:

```
psycopg2.connect("host=example.com 
                  user=user
                  dbname=whatever 
                  sslrootcert=cacert.crt
                  sslcert=user.crt
                  sslkey=user.nopassword.key
                  sslmode=verify-full")
```

In both cases everything works ok, but I have two questions:

1. Is `{verify, verify_peer}` in `epgsql` option equivalent to `sslmode=verify-ca`?
2. How to configure `sslmode=verify-full`?

---

Why I think answer to the first question is yes:
http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html, section "ssl option descriptions - common for server and client":

Default option verify_fun in verify_peer mode:

```
{fun(_,{bad_cert, _} = Reason, _) ->
     {fail, Reason};
    (_,{extension, _}, UserState) ->
     {unknown, UserState};
    (_, valid, UserState) ->
     {valid, UserState};
    (_, valid_peer, UserState) ->
         {valid, UserState}
 end, []}
```

This will fail when an error is `{bad_cert, unknown_ca}`.